# jqGrid Filter Toolbar initial value for dropdown not triggering

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having a jqgrid in my mvc view page, created as below

```
  $("#jqgrid").jqGrid({
  url: "/Consultant/GetAll",
        colNames: ['ConsultantId', 'Email', 'Status', 'Status'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'ConsultantId', index: 'ConsultantId', hidden: true },
            { name: 'ContactEmail', index: 'ContactEmail', sortable: true, search: true, autowidth: true, stringResult: true, shrinkToFit: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['cn'] } },
            { name: 'Status', index: 'Status', hidden: true },
            {
                name: 'StatusChangeLink', sortable: true, autowidth: true, search: true, stype: "select",
                searchoptions: {
                    value: "0:[All];1:Active;2:Inactive", sopt: ['eq'], defaultValue: 1,
                }, align: 'center',
            },
        ],
        pager: '#pjqgrid',
        datatype: "json",
        rowNum: 10,
        autowidth: true,
        shrinkToFit: true,
        height: 'auto',
        forceFit: true,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        sortname: 'ConsultantId',
        sortorder: "desc",
        loadonce: false,
        viewrecords: true,
        toolbarfilter: true,
        gridview: true,
        ignoreCase: true,
        viewsortcols: [true, 'vertical', true],
        ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
        jsonReader: {
        root: 'Rows',
            page: 'Page',
            total: 'Total',
            records: 'Records',
            repeatitems: false
        },
        gridComplete: function () {
            var ids = jQuery("#jqgrid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
            for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                var column = ids[i];
                var row = $("#jqgrid").getRowData(column);
                var statusChangeLink = '';
                if (row['Status'] == 'true')
                    statusChangeLink = "<input type='checkbox' id='chk" + i + "' checked class='switch-input' onclick='ToggleIsActive(" + row['ConsultantId'] + ")'><label for='chk" + i + "' class='switch-label'></label>";
                else if (row['Status'] == 'false')
                    statusChangeLink = "<input type='checkbox' id='chk" + i + "' class='switch-input' onclick='ToggleIsActive(" + row['ConsultantId'] + ")'><label for='chk" + i + "' class='switch-label'></label>";

                $("#jqgrid").jqGrid('setRowData', column, { StatusChangeLink: statusChangeLink });
            }
        },
        loadingText: 'Loading Consultants..',
        noRecordText: 'No Records found',
   });
   $("#jqgrid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { searchOnEnter: false, enableClear: false, defaultSearch: "cn", autosearch: true });
   var grid = $("#jqgrid");
   grid[0].triggerToolbar();
```

I am doing search, sort and paging from server side and is working perfectly so far. my current requirement is, when i display the grid for the first time, i have to show only the active (status) consultants in the grid. user can change the dropdown value if he need to see the inactive items or all items. the statuslink dropdown is set with the selected value Active with the above code, but the filter is not passed to the server side (the Status is 0 when we check the model in server side). What should i do else in order to make it working?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: @Paulo Diogo, yes, i tried that, but it didn't work